# starting unix daemon with python/paramiko

Tags: python, unix, paramiko

I have an interesting issue with a service on one of my servers I need to start/stop via a command line tool I am writing in Python.

Script runs without problems. It basically connects to the server using the Paramiko module, executes a commend using the SSHClient of said module and prints the stdout.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function

import os
import sys
import paramiko

username = "root"
password = "TOPSECRET"
servicename = "xy"
server = "192.168.1.2"

sshclient = paramiko.SSHClient()
sshclient.load_system_host_keys()

sshclient.connect(server, username=username, password=password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = sshclient.exec_command("service servicename stop", get_pty=True)
stdin.close()
for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
    print(line)
```

executing this will give me an output like

```
Service xy has stopped
```

which is exactly what I expected. If the service was running beforehand and I check now manually at the server, it has stopped. So the code is working just fine and is doing what I want it to do.

But god forbid if I change the whole "stop" into a "start":

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = sshclient.exec_command("service servicename start", get_pty=True)
stdin.close()
for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
    print(line)
```

Executing this will also give me the result as required. E.g.:

```
Service xy has started
```

except that If I now try to connect to said service on said server or check manually, it is not running. Anyhow, running the command `service xy start` manually at the server will start the service just fine.

Yeah - I know its bad practice, but I use the root account to start/stop the service in the script. This is to make sure it has nothing to do with any permission issues.

Honestly, I am at least a bit clueless why the stop works just fine and the start won't. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Also the following will fail interestingly. Scenario: The service is running at the time the command is executed.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = sshclient.exec_command("service servicename stop && service servicename start", get_pty=True)
stdin.close()
for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
    print(line)
```

This will stop the service, output the confirmation that the service has stopped, FAILS to start the service then, yet outputs that the service would have started. After executing this, the service is not running.

Comment: Exactly what service are we talking about here? If you run from your client command line ssh root@server  "service servicename start"  what will happen? The same or something different?

Comment: I am talking about a service I coded myself. When I run "service x start" on the shell itself, it starts normally. If I try the version you provided, it starts as well.

Comment: I would in this case either examine the server side startup logs of failed attempts. Location of these logs depends on OS version.   There is no particular reason, why your script would not work. Have you also read stderr of your script if there were anything helpful?  I'm afraid there won't be any generic advice as the issue must be somewhere in your start script. If you can capture start script output, you could also add echos there to ensure it tries to execute the binary instead of failing an if somewhere etc.

Comment: Do you use your "servicename" variable anywhere in your script?

Comment: there are no logs the service produces when starting up as it is simply not even TRYING to start. it simply does NOT. It is like something blocks the command from being executed for some reason. If I start it manually, logs are produced as expected.

Comment: The "servicename" variable is actually only in the example. In the script, it is the hardcoded servicename

Comment: I know this is not very helpful, but I have debugged similar issues by adding echo a, echo b, echo c etc. after every line in my script. Does your script even execute, or does it branch out somewhere and actually not do anything? As you get the "service started" message, it probably runs but a conditional statement goes wrong somewhere.  You could also modify your post and add the startup script there, just to give us an idea how you are starting the service.